# How to have other language field in Europecv?

Tags: europecv

I cannot find this parameter in the [documentation](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/europecv).
It has been used in the template, source [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/52fb89ad34a287a85245b478/v/1/pdf?inline=true&name=Europecv)

[image]

Minimal example

```
\documentclass[utf8,helvetica,narrow]{europecv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required to draw the logo
\usepackage[right=2.5cm]{geometry} % language table impossible otherwise

\begin{document}
\begin{europecv}

\ecvsection{Personal Skills}
\ecvmothertongue[0.5cm]{Finnish}\ecvlanguageheader{(*)}
\ecvlanguage[0.5cm]{Latvian} % TODO this parameter field is unknown to have Other languages like above
\ecvlanguage{English}{\ecvCOne}{\ecvCTwo}{\ecvCOne}{\ecvCOne}{\ecvCTwo}

\end{europecv}
\end{document}
```

**How can you have *other language(s)* -field in Europecv?**

Comment: You should know by now, how *important* a minimal example is for helpers to understand a situation.

Comment: I only see a PDF in the link. My crystal ball is misted over and the usual oracles I ask for help don't answer.

Comment: How about `\ecvlanguage`?

Comment: @egreg Minimal example provided. Thank you for notice! @Johannes_B `\evclanguage` not working to provide other languases. Or do you have some idea how?

Comment: The example doesn't compile.

Comment: @egreg This line is pseudoline: `\ecvlanguage[0.5cm]{Latvian} % TODO this parameter field is unknown to have Other languages like above`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: masiEuropecvLanguages]

```
\documentclass[utf8,helvetica,narrow,booktabs]{europecv}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[right=2.5cm]{geometry} % language table impossible otherwise

\begin{document}
\begin{europecv}
    \ecvsection{Personal Skills}
    \ecvmothertongue[0.5cm]{Finnish}
    Other Languages & \large English, German and
    French\tabularnewline[1ex]\ecvlanguageheader{(*)}
    \ecvlanguage[2cm]{English}{\ecvCOne}{\ecvCTwo}{\ecvCOne}{\ecvCOne}{\ecvCTwo}
\end{europecv}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your excellent answer! Happy Christmas!